# SBT tab completion not working in interactive mode

Tags: sbt

When attempting to use tab completion with the run-main command I get the response "{invalid input}".  I have used SBT in the past with the same project I am working on and tab completion worked just fine.  The only differences are that I have upgraded my work station to Ubuntu 16.04.  I cannot think of any other differences (though I could totally be wrong about that).  I have looked all over stack overflow (and many other sites) looking for some help on this issue.

For instance I suppose it could be that there are issues with the project definition files for my project.  Even if that's the case, I wouldn't know how to fix them (I didn't actually initiate the project so I didn't write those files).

Comment: What are you trying to complete? `sbt` has always had trouble autocompleting things with `-` in them.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond.  To partly answer your question, I have used SBT for a couple of years now and never had trouble with run-main before.  Also, no one else in my lab can reproduce my problem on their machines.  Also, even _after_ I have fully typed a command to run a project, tab completion still will not work even with the same class I just called.  I can only get previous entries using the up arrow.  Thanks for the response though!

Comment: Same happening in here...

Comment: same here too. very frustrating. all works as expected on work projects (luckily) but getting same issue on personal projects. usually generated by Giter8TemplatePlugin not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly used Ubuntu 16.04 with SBT programs without significant problems. Most of the SBT command-line related problems I have encountered on Ubuntu were caused by one or more of the following:

- `jline` - SBT forked an early version of `jline 2` and the world moved on to `jline 3`; SBT got left behind, so lots of issues since solved by the `jline` community have not made their way into SBT. [Try out various jline settings](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/562#issuecomment-19909416) and see if that helps.
- Your console might not have [bash tab completion installed or imported](https://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/28/turn-on-bash-smart-completion/).

Comment: This is correct. IIRC, the error message that the OP complains about was caused by a jline upgrade. What I did is to downgrade it.